# Torus 3d in javaFX 2.x

Tags: 3d, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-3d

I've Stage which is divided by Split Panel, and I wants on the right pane create a 3D torus.
First: I don't know what can I create torus.
Second: I don't know on what kind of obiect can I create this Torus. Pane enough?

Please for help.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to create an embedded 3D scene with a Torus using JavaFX 2.x without a lot of custom coding on your part.  However this becomes easy if you use JavaFX 8 and the third party 3D library F(X)yz:  http://birdasaur.github.io/FXyz/

F(X)yz has a Torus object:

`/src/org/fxyz/shapes/Torus.java`

You can see how to use it with the provided test code:

`/src/org/fxyz/tests/TorusTest.java`

Part of your question was how to place the 3D object into your existing JavaFX scene using the Split Pane.  The Split Pane doesn't care if its content is 3D but you should use a SubScene to embed the 3D content into the 3D scene.

Example:

```
SubScene subScene = subScene = new SubScene(sceneRoot, sceneWidth, sceneHeight, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
subScene.setFill(Color.STEELBLUE);
Camera 3DCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(true); 
3Dcamera.setNearClip(0.1);
3Dcamera.setFarClip(100000.0);
3Dcamera.setFieldOfView(35);
3Dcamera.setTranslateZ(cameraDistance);
subScene.setCamera(3Dcamera);
//Add the subscene to the SplitPane
mySplitPane.getChildren().add(subScene);
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read how to create torus http://blogoben.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/webgl-basics-7-colored-torus/

Comment: A WebGL implementation is a good resource to learn how to program 3D geometry but it will be difficult for a beginner to port the specific implementation to a JavaFX 3D Mesh implementation.  Also the user needs insight into adding the 3D content to an existing JavaFX GUI.